# isnt this the opposite of how a decorator works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api, python-decorators

Yesterday we upgraded our slackclient module in python and needed to change some code based on this migration guide for the RTM API.

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/wiki/Migrating-to-2.x

Here is my code...

```
import slack

slack_token = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']

rtmclient = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_token)

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def parse_message(**payload):
    data = payload['data']
    channel_id = data['channel']
    print(data)
    print(channel_id)

rtmclient.start()
```

I had never worked with a Python decorator before this.

After reading up on decorators, it was my understanding that the decorator `slack.RTMClient.run_on` would be called if I were to call the function `parse_message`.

This code appears to be doing the opposite.

Why/how does this code work when `rtmclient.start()` is called?

Comment: The decorator is called instead of your function, true, but the decorator then handles calling your function.  Depending on how the decorator is coded it may call your function then do its own logic, or it may do its own logic then call your function (or both). A decorator is a wrapper. It wraps code around your function so it can do additional logic beyond what your function is actually programmed to do.

Comment: The decorator is called when you *define* your function. It's just syntactic sugar for defining `parse_message` followed by `parse_message = slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')(parse_message)`. Perhaps the decorator doesn't actually return a function (whether the original or a new one) to bind to `parse_message`, but if there is no intent to ever *call* the function explicitly, that hardly matters. Here, the decorator appears to be used to register a callback.

Comment: @error this reads like an answer in comments. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, the comment kind of expanded on me while writing it. @tobias_k's answer covers everything important, though.

Comment: Can we stop saying syntactic sugar.  It means nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not familiar with that particular API, but

```
@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def parse_message(**payload):
    ...
```

is essentially the same as

```
def parse_message(**payload):
    ...

parse_message = slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')(parse_message)
```

The decorator is not called when the function is called, but when it is declared. It will then usually define and return a new function that will be called instead of the original function, e.g. with additional logging, memoization, and the like.

But it is also perfectly possible for a decorator to just return the original version of the function,<sup>1</sup> but e.g. register that function as a callback for some events.

A very much simplified example:

```
my_callbacks = []
def register(f):
    my_callbacks.append(f)
    return f

@register
def foo():
    print("calling foo")


for f in my_callbacks:
    f()
```

<sup>1)</sup> As noted in comments, [this decorator](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/slack/rtm/client.py#L138) seems to not even return the original function but `None`, meaning that the function will no longer be directly callable after being decorated, only via the callback.

Comment: In fact, [`run_on` *doesn't* return the original function](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/slack/rtm/client.py#L138).

Comment: @chepner Interesting. With `decorator` returning `None`, this means that the function will be `None` after being decorated and is then no longer useable as a regular function but only via the callback.